# Getting value of a generic inherited private field

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm having some trouble trying to access private fields from an inherited generic class. It throws me an exception with the object owner I'm using to try to get the value, but if I use that same owner to get the field from a field directly declared with that generic type it works fine.

Here's my fields:

```
public class Bool : DebugProperty<bool>
{
    ...
}

DebugProperty<bool> m_nonIngeriteedBool;
Bool m_inheritedBool;
```

Here's how I get the value from m_nonIngeriteedBool field:

```
FieldInfo field = owner.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

Type type = field.FieldType;

FieldInfo m_value = type.GetField("m_value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

object val = m_value.GetValue(field.GetValue(owner)).ToString();
```

This works fine and returns the proper value, but for m_inheritedBool I can't find how to make it work. Here's what I currently have:

```
FieldInfo field = owner.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

Type type = field.FieldType;

while (type != typeof(DebugProperty<>))
{
    type = type.BaseType;

    if (type.IsGenericType)
        type = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    
    if (type == null)
        break;
}

FieldInfo m_value = type.GetField("m_value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

object val = m_value.GetValue(field.GetValue(owner)).ToString();
```

This returns the proper m_value field, but when trying to get the value fails throwing the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Field m_value defined on type DebugProperty`1[T] is not a field on the target object which is of type Test+Bool.
Parameter name: obj
```

What object should I use to return the correct value?

Comment: Why are you looking at the generic type definition? You can't have an instance of `T` because it's not an actual type, so getting its value doesn't make nay sense. Don't treat `DebugProperty<bool>` differently.

Comment: @madreflection Because without doing it, it doesn't find the FieldInfo. Using the same code as the non inherited field returns null in the GetField section

Comment: Your code is fragmented. Please [edit] it into a [mre].

Comment: Oh, inheritance... Include `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`. Alternatively, you wanted the `BaseType` property, not the generic type definition. Close-constructed types are a lateral relationship to the generic type definition, but finding something in the inherited class requires that you go up in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after playing more with it I found a way to make it work. This approach works with both cases without problems. This was thanks to @madreflection comment.

```
static object GetValue(object owner, string name)
{
    FieldInfo field = owner.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    Type type = field.FieldType;

    if (!type.IsGenericType || type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(DebugProperty<>))
    {
        do
        {
            type = type.BaseType;
            
            if (type == null)
                return null;

        } while (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(DebugProperty<>));
    }

    FieldInfo m_value = type.GetField("m_value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    object fieldVal = field.GetValue(owner);
    object val = m_value.GetValue(fieldVal).ToString();

    return val;
}
```